# PHP7 MSSQL SqlServer Nginx Laravel Forge - Bad Gateway

Tags: sql-server, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I've been trying to get my Laravel Forge Ubuntu server to connect to a remote MSSQL server. I've finally got the server set up to where it can reach the remote database and make queries through terminal. However, when I try and use the connection within Laravel I'm getting a "502 Bad Gateway". I've done quite a bit of searching at this point and I'm still none the wiser on how to debug this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've included my nginx and php-fpm logs edited for security.

**var/log/nginx/XXX.co-error.log**

```
2017/06/12 13:51:40 [error] 5682#5682: *84 recv() failed (104:
Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream,
client: 000.000.000.000, server: XXX.co, request: "GET
/tools/labels/refreshsalesorderitems HTTP/1.1", upstream:
"fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "XXX.co",
referrer: "http://XXX.co/tools/labels"
```

**var/log/php7.1-fpm.log**

```
[12-Jun-2017 13:51:40] WARNING: [pool www] child 8538 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 3135.874644
seconds from start
[12-Jun-2017 13:51:40] NOTICE: [pool www] child 9087 started
```

**core dump backtrace**

```
/etc/php/7.1/fpm: Success.
[New LWP 22567]
Core was generated by `php-fpm: pool www                                                            '.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007fdb7d6bfbe9 in ?? ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007fdb7d6bfbe9 in ?? ()
#1  0x372e350a0000005b in ?? ()
#2  0x3921ba89f34d7f00 in ?? ()
#3  0x0004000400000006 in ?? ()
#4  0x000055d8b19043a0 in ?? ()
#5  0x000055d8b1904810 in ?? ()
#6  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```